# Are comments in Inno Setup [Code] section stored to a generated installer?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Anyone knows if the `//Comments` in the `[Code]` section of the `.iss` file are stored also in the compiled `Setup.exe` file or not?

In other words... if someone unpacks the `Setup.exe` file, can he retrieve the comments in some manner or absolutely not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are removed already by a [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/). So the comments do not even make it to the compiler (which would remove them too anyway), let alone to the binary.

You can easily check that by calling [`SaveToFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=savetofile) at the end of your `.iss` script and checking the generated `Preprocessed.iss` file:

```
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

For example this:

```pascal
[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  { Secret comment }
  Result := True;
end;

#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

... will be filtered to this by the preprocessor:

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: Interesting. 